# Progress calculator for JSON file while looping through it

Tags: python, json, algorithm

I've been working on the project that has to do with data processing. The format utilized inside python application is JSON. I have a task that loops through huge JSON file and makes some sort of calculations. In fact, it can take a lot of time so in order to show the progress of this process I came up with small algorithm for the calculation.

Code sample is:

```
def update_progress_by_five(self, current, total):
    five_percent_length = int(0.05 * total)
    if five_percent_length > 0 and current % five_percent_length == 0:
        progress = 5 * current / five_percent_length
        progress = 100 if progress > 100 else progress
        print("Progress", progress)
        self.task.set_progress(progress)
```

It works pretty much on average JSON files, however some cases happen when the progress does not reach to 100 and I have no idea why. It simply stops on 95 and that's all there is to it.

Comment: Unless `current` only increments by 1 on each call, the `current % five_percent_length == 0` is going to cause problems.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the result of `0.05 * total` is a float that means the entire file length is not divisible by `int(0.05 * total)` , in other words
in the final call when current is equal to total this `current % five_percent_length == 0` never evaluates to true . add a condition to set the progress to 100% when `current==total`

Comment: `five_percent_length` is the rounded-down result of the computation, so it will definitely hit the condition at 100% if nonzero.

Comment: For example if the file length is 113 , then int(113*0.05)=5 and if you try 113%5 you would get 3 , so no in some cases the condition would not trigger .

Comment: Sure. But with `five_percent_length` being 5 in your example, `current` will eventually reach `100`, which in turn will be computed to 100%.